# Error 438 on Autofilter using VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to simplify code previously used in a file with the below.
The original was really repetitive and copies and pastes filtered data depending on the file name into the correct file.
I am however getting an run time error 438 on:

```
With NT.AutoFilter = True
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Sub Split()
Dim WBNames As Variant
Dim Master As Workbook
Dim NT As Worksheet
Dim NTRange As Range
Dim NTCheck As Range
Dim NTCopy As Range
Dim LR As Long
Dim LR1 As Long
Dim i As Long

WBNames = Array("Buffalo Bayou.xlsb", "Central Pacific.xlsb", "Copper Canyon.xlsb", "Glacier Express.xlsb", "Great Northern.xlsb", "Maharajas Express.xlsb", "Mobile & Ohio.xlsb", "Northern Pacific.xlsb", "Orient Express.xlsb", "Pennsylvania.xlsb", "Qinghai Tibet.xlsb", "Santa Fe.xlsb", "Shinkansen.xlsb", "Southern Pacific.xlsb", "The Ghan.xlsb", "The Tazara.xlsb", "Trans Siberian.xlsb", "Tren Crucero.xlsb", "West Highland.xlsb")

Set Master = ThisWorkbook
Set NT = Master.Sheets("New Transactions")

Let LR = NT.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set NTRange = NT.Range("A1:Z1")
Set NTCheck = NT.Range("J2:J" & LR)
Set NTCopy = NT.Range("A2:W" & LR)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False

For i = LBound(WBNames) To UBound(WBNames)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim WBName As String
    WBName = WBNames(i)
    Dim LRx As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = workbooks(WBName).Sheets("Worksheet")
    Let LRx = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set WS = workbooks.Open(WBName).Sheets("Worksheet")
        Let LRx = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not WS Is Nothing Then
        If Not NT Is Nothing Then
            With NT.AutoFilter = True
                With NTRange
                    .AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:=Replace(WBName, ".xlsb", "")
                    .AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="#N/A"
                    If NTCheck.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 0 Then
                        NTCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                        With WS
                            .Range("A" & LRx + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                        End With
                    End If
                End With
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = True

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line? Just remove it and its corresponding `End With`.